# Rails 6 Showing unknown key :on

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

before_save :balance_status, :on => :update

it is throwing "Unknown key: :on. Valid keys are: :if, :unless, :prepend"
in Rails-6

Answer (score 0):

`before_save` is used for both create and update. You should use `before_update :balance_status` instead.

Comment: before update was deprecated years ago: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/before_update

Answer (score 0):

In rails 6 the option `on` does not exists for `before_save`, see the official documentation for more info. You can use `before_commit`.